# CAKeyframeAnimation to create fireball like in Siri

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make an animation that looks like the fireball that flies around the Siri microphone icon when it's looking for information. Basically it's an object that flies around a circle and leaves a trail behind it.

Any ideas on how to pull that off?

Here's what I have so far:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *a = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
a.duration = 2.0;
a.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
a.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.frame].CGPath;
[test.layer addAnimation:a forKey:@"moveCircle"];
```

EDIT: the trail is the hard part

Answer (score 0):

Why not create it in Photoshop and then rotate the image?